# SQL Returning remaining rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table of on hand quantity for a list of parts. I have a second table with a series of order ship dates and required quantities.

I want to return the ship date of the next order that we will not have anymore inventory for.

For example:

Table 1, our on hand quantity for parts A, B, and C:

```
Name   Qty-Have
A      10
B      10
C      5
```

Table 2, Next two months of future orders for parts A, B, and C:

```
Name   Due          Qty-Need
A      11/10/17     4
A      11/15/17     6
A      11/20/17     3
A      11/25/17     10
B      11/12/17     4
B      12/15/17     4
B      12/29/17     4
C      11/10/17     7
```

Result, the earliest order date for when we will have insufficient inventory:

```
Name   Next Due         Qty-Want         
A      11/20/17         13
B      12/29/17         2   
C      11/10/17         2
```

I know I can do a grouping of Table 2 and subtract inventory to get Qty-Want, but I do not know how to get the next shipment date of the next uncovered order.

The first two orders of part A we have inventory, and I would like to know that we do not have enough for the third order, due 11/20/17 and we should make 13 parts to cover all remaining demand.

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Why you have values `11/10/17 | 2` in the `C` row?

Comment: SQL-Server and bad math! Sorry, table 2, C value should be 7 (or the result should not have a row for C, but the former is my intention)

Comment: Why 7 in `C` row?

Comment: @RadimBača 7 in the C row (table 2) to show there is a need for 7 pcs of C, however we only have 5 on hand, therefore we want 2 pcs by 11/10/17 (results table). I've updated the question sorry about that

Comment: Ok, and do you have window functions available? It would be nice if you respond to our answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have window functions available (SQL Server or MySQL 8 and above) use the following query:

```
select h.name Name, min(o.due) Next_Due, max(o.sumQty) - h.Qtyhave Qty_Want
from
(
  select *, sum(QtyNeed) over (partition by name order by due) sumQty
  from orders
) o
right join onHand h on o.name = h.name and o.sumQty > h.Qtyhave
group by h.name, h.Qtyhave
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c11637331356660978cfbcbcbe69cc73) - works for SQL Server as well as for MySQL 8 and above

**Result**

```
Name    Next Due    Qty-Want
----------------------------------
A       11/20/17    13
B       12/29/17    2
C       11/10/17    2
```

Comment: Thanks for such a complete solution and your patience working with an incomplete question

Comment: I did just realize, wouldn't a right join in your query not return orders with no quantity at all on hand? Assuming that not every part in the Orders table (2) will be in Inventory table (1)

Comment: @JoshuaZastrow the right join will return on hand parts that were not ordered at all, or that have enough quantity. I put it there since you originally had part `C` in the result and it had enough Qty. If you remove `RIGHT` then the on hand parts that have enough quantity are not included.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a sum window function to compute a running total by 'name', and observe where it goes negative:

```
select ord.name,
       ord.due,
       ord.qty,
       q.qty - ord.ord_sum inventory
from (  select *, 
                sum(qty) over (partition by name order by Due) ord_sum
        from fut_orders ) ord
inner join quantity q
    on ord.name = q.name
```

order by ord.name, ord.due

Answer (score 1):

This approach involves creating a view in MySQL. The view contains a rolling cumulative sum of the future inventory.  The current Qty-have inventory is subtracted from the sum.  Some rows will therefore have a negative value, and they are eliminated with the `HAVING` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW future_orders AS
(SELECT 
  t2.name, 
  t2.due, 
  t1.qty_have as qty_have, 
  t2.qty_need, 
  (SELECT SUM(fo.qty_need) FROM table_2 fo WHERE fo.name = t2.name AND fo.due <= t2.due)-qty_have as qty_want
FROM table_2 t2
LEFT JOIN table_1 t1 ON t1.name = t2.name
HAVING qty_want > 0);
```

Once the view is created, query for the earliest date and the latest date, for both 'Next Due' and 'Qty-Want' respectively:

```
SELECT 
  t1.name, 
  (SELECT fo.due FROM future_orders fo WHERE fo.name = t1.name ORDER BY fo.due ASC LIMIT 1) as 'Next Due',
  (SELECT fo.qty_want FROM future_orders fo WHERE fo.name = t1.name ORDER BY fo.due DESC LIMIT 1) as 'Qty-Want'
FROM table_1 t1
WHERE 1;
```

This gives you the result you were looking for: next shipment date for the next order that will be uncovered, plus the quantity required to fulfill all the remaining demand.  'C' is returned as `NULL` because it actually does not require any inventory to be ordered.